# Unable to find jaro wrinkler package in apache spark (using R or python or scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, sparkr

I want to do string comparisons using jaro wrinkler algorithm. I can do the same using the R software or python but not with Apache spark (R, Python etc).
I have to implement the string comparisons using Apache Spark (clusters) as I'll be reading lot of data. 
            I am unable to find the required library for the algorithm using R or python in Apache Spark. So can anyone help me with this.

Thanks.

Srikanth.

Comment: Welcome to SO @srikanth. Please be sure to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what topics can you ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). In particular "_questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_".

Comment: Sure I'll be not asking abt the s/w library from next time. I see that there is no package for jaro wrinkler in spark documentation , so I'll be writing the code for the same. I'll publish the details when its done

Comment: Thanks. In practice you should be able to use the same tools as in your local code (it is more complicated with R but should work with Python or JVM languages).